# What is the fastest way to map a value from a dictionary to a subset of a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with questionnaire data. The scores on some of the answers need to be inverted for further analysis. So what I want to do is the following:

1. Select the rows with questions where the score is to be inverted;
2. Map the score to the new score using a dictionary.

All the relevant columns in my DataFrame are `dtype` 'category'. Below, I have set up a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a list of scores and a dictionary to invert the scores:
lst = ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
lst_rev = list(reversed(lst))
dct = dict(zip(lst, lst_rev))

# create the example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'],
                   'B':lst},
                   dtype='category')

# create a list for selecting the specific rows that need to be remapped:
sel = ['b', 'c']
```

#### First method

The first method I have tried:

```
%timeit df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: dct.get(x['B']) if x['A'] in sel else x['B'], axis=1)
```

yields the following result:
`2.6 ms ± 36.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

#### Second method

The second method was considerably slower (on my data set it seemed to perform far worse than this test would suggest):

```
mask = df['A'].isin(sel)
%timeit df.loc[mask, 'B'] = df.loc[mask, 'B'].map(dct)
```

yielding: `3.56 ms ± 50.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

These approaches work, but both perform rather poorly on my data set. Does anyone have a faster method? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
df['B'] = pd.np.where(df['A'].isin(sel), df['B'].map(dct), df['B'])

>>> df
   A  B
0  a  u
1  b  x
2  a  w
3  c  v
4  a  y
```

Or just `loc`, but all in one go, and without re-calling it a second time:

```
df.loc[df.A.isin(sel), 'B'] = df['B'].map(dct)

>>> df
   A  B
0  a  u
1  b  x
2  a  w
3  c  v
4  a  y
```

On a large dataframe (10000 entries), `np.where` took about 0.00197 seconds, whereas your `apply` method took about 0.351 seconds:

```
import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], 10000),
                   'B':np.random.choice(['u','v','w','x','y'], 10000)})

def method1(df=df, sel=sel):
    return pd.np.where(df['A'].isin(sel), df['B'].map(dct), df['B'])


def method2(df=df,sel=sel):
    return df.apply(lambda x: dct.get(x['B']) if x['A'] in sel else x['B'], axis=1)

>>> timeit.timeit(method1, number=100) / 100
0.001973706789995049
>>> timeit.timeit(method2, number=10) / 10
0.3509046911000041

>>> (method1() == method2()).all()
True
```

Comment: `df.B.mask(df.A.isin(sel),df.B.map(dct))`

Answer (score 3):

#### `numpy.in1d`

```
b = df.B.values
a = df.A.values
m = np.in1d(a, sel)

b[m] = [*map(dct.get, b[m])]

df

   A  B
0  a  u
1  b  x
2  a  w
3  c  v
4  a  y
```

---

Less invasive

```
b = df.B.values
a = df.A.values
m = np.in1d(a, sel)

np.where(m, [*map(dct.get, b)], b)
```

---

#### `map`

```
f = lambda a, b: dct.get(b) if a in sel else b

[*map(lambda t: f(*t), zip(df.A, df.B))]

['u', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'y']
```

Comment: I bet both `numpy` solutions should much faster than `pandas` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using a filled [`numpy.ma.masked_array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.filled.html):

```
a = df.A.values
b = df.B.values
c = list(map(dct.get, b))

out = np.ma.masked_array(b, np.in1d(a, sel)).filled(c)
```

```
array(['u', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'y'], dtype=object)
```

On smaller arrays, broadcasting offers a minor speedup:

```
a = np.array(df.A)
b = np.array(df.B)
c = list(map(dct.get, b))

mask = (a[:, None] == sel).any(1)

np.ma.masked_array(b, mask).filled(c)
```